mqtt not send data when qos 2
I am creating class for connect and send the data throw mqtt. when the qos 0 or 1, it works fine. but in qos 2, its not send the data.
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt


class MqttClient:
    """ Manage connection """

    def __init__(self, clientId, port, ip) -> None:
        self.clientId = clientId
        self.port = port
        self.broker = ip
        self.connect()

    def connect(self):
        """ Connects to an mqtt client """
        client = mqtt.Client(client_id=self.clientId)
        client.connect(self.broker, self.port)
        self._client = client

    def pub(self, topic: str, payload: str):
        self.client.publish(topic, payload, qos=2)

    def disconnect(self):
        self.client.disconnect()

    @property
    def client(self):
        return self._client

this is my class. I send the data and check by mqtt explorer. qos 0 or 1 data recived, but not in 2

QOS 2 messages require sending multiple packets back and forth to the broker. The Paho client can only process these multiple packets if the network loop is running.
https://eclipse.dev/paho/files/paho.mqtt.python/html/index.html#network-loop
You are not starting the network loop anywhere in your code.
Simplest fix is to add client.loop_start() to the end of your connect function
    def connect(self):
        """ Connects to an mqtt client """
        client = mqtt.Client(client_id=self.clientId)
        client.connect(self.broker, self.port)
        self._client = client
        client.loop_start()

...


    def disconnect(self):
        self.client.disconnect()
        self.client.loop_stop()


Thanks for responding. I have an doubt with loop. Loop is used for subscribe. Is that need for connecting and subscribing?

The loop is needed for everything, especially when using higher QOS levels

But it receives the data slowly. I send the data every second. but it receives the data with more gaps. is this the reason for QoS 2?
